# unable to connect ionic app to mysql using Wamp server

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework

Hi I am new to ionic framework. I am trying to connect MySQL from ionic app using wamp server. But I am not able to connect. this is my controller.

**JS:**

```
$scope.buyItem = function (itemName, itemImage) {
        $http.post("http://localhost/postdata.php")
          .success(function (response) {
            alert(" " + response);
          })
          .error(function (err) {
            alert('error  '+err);
          });
      }
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

        function getCon(){
        define('HOST','localhost');
        define('DB','grocerydb');
        define('USER','root');
        define('PASS','');

        $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
        return $con
        ?>

            <?php
        include('getConnection.php');
        $con = getCon();

        if($con!=null)
           echo 'connected'; 
        else 
           echo 'not connected';

        ?>
```

**i used C://wamp/localhost url also. but not worked.please help me where i am wrong. Thanks.
**

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible to connect directly to a database through Ionic. 
And as far as my research went I only came up with solutions containing an API.
You should take a look at: [Creating an Ionic App with MySQL and Backand](http://blog.ionic.io/creating-an-ionic-app-with-mysql-and-backand/)

It will give you an idea what to expect.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your httpd.con in Apache and add in Directory and directory C/wamp/www/ the following: `allow from all`